# How to use a temperature raster (e.g., PRISM) to constrain temperature values in a thin plate spline regression and interpolation

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, smoothing, thin-plate-splines

I have point data with temperature, latitude, longitude, and elevation. I am interpolating across space to the extent of those points, and have been using elevation as a covariate in the `fields::Tps`. However, this is for paleoclimate reconstructions.

So, I know what the modern day temperature surface looks like (i.e., the distribution of temperature across space). It seems reasonable to use this temperature surface rather than elevation in some way in order to constrain the interpolation. In other words, as interpolation takes place between a point (with a known temperature) and another random point in space, is it possible to say if between these two points is extremely different than the modern surface, then it is assigned a cutoff value (almost like a threshold)? I would like to do this in a way that would be quantitative, and not me just choosing a threshold. This would almost be like have a calibrated dataset and then predictions from the point data.

Here, I provide some sample code for what I have done. But I also include the PRISM data as well.

```
library(fields)
library(dplyr)
library(elevatr)
library(sf)
library(raster)

# Create a bounding box for cropping elevation data.
swcolorado <- c(
  "xmin" = -109,
  "ymin" = 36,
  "xmax" = -105,
  "ymax" = 38.25
)  %>%
  sf::st_bbox() %>%
  sf::st_as_sfc() %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(crs = 4326) %>%
  sf::st_transform(crs = 4326)

# Get elevation data, then crop with the bounding box, and aggregate (so the code runs quicker).
elev.raster <- elevatr::get_elev_raster(swcolorado, z = 5) %>%
  raster::crop(elevation, swcolorado) %>%
  raster::aggregate(fact = 12)

# Temperature dataframe with temperature, longitude, latitude, and elevation.
temp.points <- structure(list(long = c(-108.160375, -107.808675, -106.510525, 
-107.81571, -105.514165, -106.45052, -105.740635, -105.63166, 
-106.843695, -107.61537, -107.682735, -107.6975, -108.503889, 
-105.724665, -108.10256), lat = c(37.473105, 37.647645, 36.047665, 
37.60664, 37.569525, 37.021745, 37.71109, 38.08806, 37.611035, 
37.902105, 37.74759, 37.737778, 37.473889, 37.67773, 37.46906
), temperature = c(14.6972137463016, 14.8096938066668, 14.9004909660972, 
14.8110845322457, 9.7248919765495, 13.271146269724, 18.0169186561757, 
10.5835671771822, 10.8751447949415, 8.98234964596861, 11.8225704515042, 
11.982697080223, 19.8293764051047, 18.0406584631011, 12.8451985711037
), elev.locs = c(3024, 2694, 2932, 2706, 3589, 3054, 2293, 3449, 
3471, 3739, 3205, 3329, 2111, 2290, 3291)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L), class = "data.frame")


# Need to extract the xy grid and put in ascending order, as the fields package expects that.
elev.raster.long <- raster::xFromCol(elev.raster)
elev.raster.lat <- raster::yFromRow(elev.raster) %>%
  sort()
elev.raster.elev <- as.matrix(elev.raster)
elev.raster.elev <- elev.raster.elev

# Transpose, so that rows and columns will match the long lat lists. Then, mirror the columns so that the latitude is ascending.
elev.raster.elev <- t(elev.raster.elev) %>%
  as.data.frame()
elev.raster.elev <-
  elev.raster.elev[, order(ncol(elev.raster.elev):1)] %>%
  as.matrix()

# Put long, lat, and elevation into 1 list. Then, rename to x, y, and z.
elev.raster.list <-
  list(elev.raster.long, elev.raster.lat, elev.raster.elev)
names(elev.raster.list) <- c("x", "y", "z")

#Create the grid list, which will be used in the prediction below.
grid.list <-
  list(x = elev.raster.list$x, y = elev.raster.list$y)

# First, run the model using Tps with elevation as an independent covariate.
obj <- fields::Tps(
  # Accepts points but expects them as matrix.
  x = as.matrix(temp.points[, c("long", "lat")]),
  # The dependent variable.
  Y = temp.points$temperature,
  # Elevation as an independent covariate.
  Z = temp.points$elev.locs,
  miles = TRUE
)

# Use predictSurface on the model.
out.p <- predictSurface(obj,
                        grid.list = grid.list,
                        ZGrid = elev.raster.list,
                        extrap = TRUE)

# Then, convert to raster.
out.raster <- raster(out.p)
crs(out.raster) <- CRS('+init=EPSG:4326')
out.raster <- crop(out.raster, sf::st_bbox(c(
  "xmin" = -109,
  "ymin" = 36.0,
  "xmax" = -105,
  "ymax" = 38.25
)))
plot(out.raster)
```

To get PRISM data, for the area above:

```
library(prism)

# Need to first create a directory for the PRISM data to download and set as working directory.
setwd("~/prism_set_dl_dir")

# Then download data (only doing one layer so that it isn't a large file).
get_prism_annual("tmean", years = 2010, keepZip = FALSE, keep_pre81_months = FALSE)

# Load the PRISM data and I crop to the same extent as above.
PRISM <- raster("~/prism_set_dl_dir/PRISM_tmean_stable_4kmM3_2010_bil/PRISM_tmean_stable_4kmM3_2010_bil.bil") %>% 
  crop(sf::st_bbox(c(
  "xmin" = -109,
  "ymin" = 36.0,
  "xmax" = -105,
  "ymax" = 38.25
)))
```

This is similar to my [other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402509/what-is-the-difference-between-using-interpolate-and-predictsurface-on-a-thi), but felt that it was different enough to warrant a new question.

**EDIT** (clarifying for comment below)

So, I was thinking about using some kind of similarity/dissimilarity measure, but unsure how to do that in this context. My other thought was to use the maximum amount of change between two pixels from the modern temperature dataset (PRISM) to constrain the interpolation. I attempt to illustrate this below:

[image: illustration]

In the illustration above, the maximum change in the modern temperature dataset between 2 pixels is 3 (shown by the 2 way arrow). Therefore, there should not be a change in the interpolation greater than or equal to 3 (using absolute value) between any 2 connected pixels in the interpolation. So, you can see how the cells would change with this constraint.

[image: illustration2]

However, I'm unsure how to implement this into the workflow above, which has multiple points and elevation as a covariate.

Comment: This might be a spatial statistical methodology question rather than a GIS/Programming one, and so might be better asked on the statistics stackexchange site. Could you maybe do some diagrams to show what you want to do - perhaps in one dimension might be easier to illustrate?

Comment: @Spacedman I felt like it kind of fell in between the 2 sites, so was unsure. I have updated the post with an edit to try to more clearly illustrate my thought process with some figures to illustrate.

Comment: First off, this seems a really odd thing to do. If the model is telling you the temp is 33 in the bottom corner, then it probably has a reason. Better to understand that reason and control for it in the model (is there a missing covariate that would pull it down?) than ad-hoc set it to 23 because its smallest neighbour is 20.

Comment: Doing this statistically would seem to involve putting a strong prior belief on the max adjacent difference between cells. This would be a difficult model to fit since what affects one cell affects all of them, and you'd probably have to use a Bayesian framework like Stan, PyMC3 etc.

Comment: If you do just want to pull down the outlying values in an "ad hoc" way, then all your statistical inference goes out the window - you can't rely on the other estimates and uncertainties on those estimates any more. Imagine fitting a straight line to some points, and then going "well, the third fitted point should be not on the straight line". In summary I could tell you how to do this, but unless I'm sure this is the right thing for you, I probably wont :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the input. This definitely helps to think through it more. My statistical gut was telling me that simply using max would not be sound, as you say all the inference goes out the window. I think I'll just go back to model and think more critically about it - I think that's probably the way to go as well.